# Firebase database not work with java app

Tags: java, jsf, firebase-realtime-database

I want using firebase database for my java web app, but I have problems...
My application can not connection to firebase-batabase. When I starting my web app I getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions` error. Even if using simple java application with main method, application don't connection to db.

Comment: Did you add the firebase libs to your class path? What build tool are you using (e.g. maven)?

Comment: I'm using maven, added dependency form firebase docs... But this work if version 5.0.0 (latest version 6.3.0). Application not for android (android application good work). I want create web application (using technologies- java server faces and firebase-database, build tool- maven).